# Laravel Setting active class to navigation

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-5.4, navigationbar, laravel-blade

I want to set `active` class to my active routes, i have tried below approach but it is not working

The  `navside.blade.php` page

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu collapsible collapsible-accordion" data-collapsible="accordion">
    <li class="no-padding {{ Request::is('/manager/dashboard') ? 'active' : '' }}">
        <a class="waves-effect waves-grey" href="{!! URL::asset('/manager/dashboard')!!}">
            <i class="material-icons">settings_input_svideo</i>Dashboard
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="no-padding {{ Request::is('/manager/orders') ? 'active' : '' }}">
        <a class="waves-effect waves-grey" href="{!! URL::asset('/manager/orders')!!}">
            <i class="material-icons">shopping_cart</i>Orders
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="no-padding {{ Request::is('/manager/outlets') ? 'active' : '' }}">
        <a class="waves-effect waves-grey" href="{!! URL::asset('/manager/outlets')!!}">
            <i class="material-icons dp48">store</i>Outlets
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="no-padding {{ Request::is('/manager/reports') ? 'active' : '' }}">
        <a class="waves-effect waves-grey" href="{!! URL::asset('/manager/reports')!!}">
            <i class="material-icons dp48">receipt</i>Reports
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="no-padding {{ Request::is('/manager/manage') ? 'active' : '' }}">
        <a class="waves-effect waves-grey" href="{!! URL::asset('/manager/manage')!!}">
            <i class="material-icons dp48">input</i>Manage
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And my routes are

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'manager', 'middleware' => ['auth','roles'], 'roles' => 'manager'], function() {

    Route::get('/dashboard', 'ManagerController@index')->name('dashboard');

    Route::get('/orders', 'OrdersController@index')->name('orders');
    Route::get('/orders/{order_id}', 'OrdersController@show')->name('orderDetails');
    Route::post('/assign_orders', 'OrdersController@assignDeliveryBoy')->name('assignOrder');

    Route::get('/outlets', 'OutletsController@index')->name('outlets');

    Route::get('/reports', 'ReportsController@index')->name('reports');

});
```

I did tried some different approaches like

```
  1  {{ Request::segment(1) === 'programs' ? 'active' : null }}

  2  class="@if(Request::url()== url('/home') active @endif"
```

but they din't work ether

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:
`(Route::current()->getName() == 'routename') ? 'active' : null`

You also can make it a helper function instead of copy pasting the full if statement.

Comment: well this works, thank yo for your time really appreciate it, and what about dynamic routes like `order/{id}`

Comment: They will have route names as well if you use `Route::resource()` it will be `orders.show` but in your case it is `orderDetails` you can check all the names with the console command `php artisan route:list`